# How to say "lay on one side" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, español-neutral

I was wondering how do people say "lay on one side" in Spanish. I need it as an imperative to use at gym or something(not while you're sleeping).
I searched "tumbarse a un lado" but couldn't find any specific result.

Answer (score 7):

You can use different approaches:

> Tumbarse de lado
>
> Tumbarse del lado derecho / izquierdo
>
> Acostarse de lado
>
> Acostarse del lado derecho / izquierdo

Since "acostarse" has the connotation of laying for a long time, you can also use the verb **"[recostar](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=PhO77IXJkDXX2vNfy4MN)"**, which means *Acostarse durante un breve período de tiempo* - laying for a short period which is more related to what you would do in a gym.

As an imperative it would be:

> Túmbate (tú) / túmbese (usted) / tumbaos (vosotros) ...
>
> Acuéstate / acuéstese / acostaos ...
>
> Recuéstate / recuéstese / recostaos ...

Comment: Perhaps worth pointing out in case any Hispanophones use this to translate in the other direction is that @fedorqui has translated lie on one side not lay. However, no harm done as that is probably what the OP meant. I lie on my side but I would lay you down on your side.